# Visual Studio 2015 does not compile when generic type matches overloaded method that takes that type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My project compiles in VS 2013 but does not compile in VS 2015. Below code reproduces the compile problem. The Validator classes are actually in a 3rd party assembly so I can not change the implementation. The require class is a local class but I don't want to change the implementation because I will have to change lots of validation logic. Below is the code that does not compile in VS 2015.

```
public abstract class Validator<T> : Validator
{
    public override void DoValidate(object objectToValidate)
    {

    }
    protected abstract void DoValidate(T objectToValidate);
}

public abstract class Validator
{
    public abstract void DoValidate(object objectToValidate);
}

public abstract class ValidatorBase<T> : Validator<T>
{
    protected override void DoValidate(T objectToValidate)
    {

    }
}

public class Required : ValidatorBase<object>
{

}
```

Is there a workaround for this compilation issue? Any help would be appreciated.

The Error:

```
Severity  Code    Description                                                                                     Project  File        Line

Error     CS0534  'Required' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Validator<object>.DoValidate(object)'           Program.cs  38
```

Comment: ValidatorBase is useless anyhow.  Get rid of it.

Comment: I have added the error

Comment: I can not get rid of ValidatorBase it's a 3rd party dll (Enterprise Library)

Comment: Something that compiles in VS2013 but not in VS2015 *is* a bug, no matter what - they treat backwards compatibility *very* seriously. Nice corner case you've found there. Someone should check if this has been reported [on Roslyn's bug tracker](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3AArea-Compilers) and report it if necessary.

Comment: @Will What makes you think that?

Comment: It is interesting that the two overloads, `DoValidate(object)` and `DoValidate(T)` (which ___unify___ once you have `T` substituted by `object` in the concrete class `Required`) actually have different access modifiers (`public` and `protected`) in your case. If you remove the concrete class `Required`, will the three abstract classes alone compile, under VS2015? I suppose yes. If instead you change `Required` into `public class Required : ValidatorBase<string> { }` so that the two overloads do not unify when the `T` is substituted, will it compile then under VS2015?

Comment: Will it allow you to insert a `public class RequiredGeneric<TExample> : ValidatorBase<TExample> { }`, non-abstract as seen, in between the `ValidatorBase<>` and the `Required` classes. Such that the `Required` class inherits the other classes through this non-abstract but still generic intermediate class?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen look at it.  Compare it to `Validator<T>`.  Explain why it's needed.

Comment: @Will It contributes one concrete implementation (`override`) of a method which `Validator<T>` declares as abstract. Other classes (not shown above) could derive from `Validator<T>` (as well) and provide __different__ implementations of that method. So `ValidatorBase<T>` is useful. (Of course all the bodies are empty in the example above, but we can assume that some logic is actually in there in the real scenario; it was just cut out by the asker to provide a minimal example to reproduce the compiler error. We can also assume that all the classes contribute other members, not shown above.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Stop spinning, you're going to stir up a hurricane.  You don't need to have a base class create an empty implementation of an abstract method in order to allow others to "provide different implementations of that method". The fact that the method is abstract allows for this.

Comment: @Will If you get rid of `ValidatorBase<T>`, where do you want to put the members it has (of which one, the `override` of `DoValidate(T)`, is explicitly shown above)? Into its current base class, or into its current deriving class? How can you know skipping one level of inheritance will not affect other classes (in the same assembly or other assemblies)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen The member (not members, there's only one) it has is empty, pointless, useless, and worthless. There is no need for it. Do you not see this?  Or are you assuming that empty method isn't an empty method?  Wait, don't answer that, this conversation is stupid and is probably annoying the OP.  You assume all you want, I'm going to stay with what I'm actually given. Good day to you, sir.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski There is a report logged for this bug here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find a reason of this behavior, I failed.

I did find a workaround though. The code you posted compiles when `ValidatorBase<T>` is not abstract. I know you can't change it, but you can add another non-abstract class to the inheritance chain:

```
public class Workaround<T> : ValidatorBase<T> { }

public class Required : Workaround<object>
{

}
```

It looks like Roslyn doesn't resolve the overridden methods in abstract classes until a non-abstract derived class is defined.

Comment: Nice, that answers the question I asked **2015-10-17 00:08:48Z** in a comment to the question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I see now that you posted exactly the same in the comments. How did you figure out it would help? I ran into this solution by accident, I'm really interested what's exactly happening.